# Practices/tactics to decouple existing projects from external open source jars

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, open-source

My system is connecting to Oracle through Hibernate/JDBC. I want to restructure it using abstraction to decouple its implementation from Hibernate library. That's a backup for someday the team can switch to another JPA implementation without painful to change core business logic to adapter with new JPA implementation. What are advices in doing this?

By the way, I want some advice from gurus what are common practices/tactics to decouple existing projects from external open source jars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct dependence on standard and popular open source libraries is OK. You shouldn't consider it as a problem. For e.g I have a large code base and it depends upon joda-time, google-guava etc. Now, coming to your situation, following is my view point

1. There is very less chance that you move from one JPA implementation to another because by the time you get familiar with a particular implementation (yes implementation because you might want to optimize something or you are looking for some feature that is missing from standard JPA api) it would take some time and you really doesn't want to spend the same effort learning other implementation (business doesn't let you even if you want to ;-)).
2. Spring already abstracts most of the regularly used API's like JPA, JMS etc. so I suggest you look at that option.

Comment: Google-guava is an awesome all-in-one library. Thanks for letting me know about it. As you confirmed, it's usually ok with direct dependence. However, we occasionally need a abstraction. For example, at the present we use a cache library, but it the future, a new strong performance cache library appears. Then loosely coupling plays the role.

Answer (score 2):

You should [program against interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29#Programming_against_software_interfaces) to reduce dependencies. Your service classes -the ones that contain Business Logic- should depend on Data Access Object Interfaces instead of an specific DAO implementation. Something like this:

```
public class ImAServiceBean {

    private EntityDAO entityDAO;

    private void someBusinessLogic(){
        entityDAO.createInstance(...);
```

Were the DAO interface goes this way:

```
 public interface EntityDAO {

    void createInstance (...);
    void updateInstance(...);
```

Now you're using something like EntityHibernateDaoImpl, but if you want to change your persistence framework to MyBatis you can build an EntityMyBatisDaoImpl (which implements EntityDAO) and use that class in your Services classes with no change at all (asumming you're using some kind of dependency injection). The same thing if you use JPA, JDO or any persistance technology: your Business Logic only depends on a plain interface, and that interface can be implemented but any persistence technology, even JDBC

Comment: Thanks. Could you show up some most common design patterns (say wrapper, adapter, bridge...) you used to decouple from external library (tiles, axis, display-tag..) (Sorry if this question so general)

Comment: Can you be a little most specific? What's the dependency that is bothering you, and in what context? The answer posted is a example of Programming against interfaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)#Programming_against_software_interfaces

Comment: Not to forget DAO API and implementation should be in separate libraries, only then the decoupling would be full.

Answer (score 1):

JPA already is a separate API.  if your team uses JPA, then you should already have the ability to switch from hibernate with zero effort.